# Why I can't add lines with "echo >>" from bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have got the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

myParam='/linuxcoe'
myConfigFile='/etc/exports'

if grep -q myParam myConfigFile
  then echo "myParam string exist!"
else
 echo "Did not find string, adding"
 echo "/linuxcoe *" >> myConfigFile
fi
```

But it don't work from bash script, in config we don't have new lines.
 echo "/linuxcoe *" >> /etc/exports from console with root works good, but don't work from script, started by root. Why? How to solve it? How to add strings to config file?

Comment: Also, `grep -q -e "$myParam" "$myConfigFile"`, or the `grep` will be looking at a file named `myConfigFile`, not `/etc/exports`.

Comment: BTW, if you ran `bash -x yourscript`, you'd see that it was running `grep -q myParam myConfigFile` rather than running `grep -q /linuxcoe /etc/exports`, which would hopefully be enough information that you wouldn't have needed to ask a question here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `echo "/linuxcoe *" >> "$myConfigFile"`.  Your existing script is creating a file named `myCOnfigFile`.

Comment: Better to quote the expansion: `>>"$myConfigFile"`; that way you don't get surprises if, say, `IFS=/`.

Comment: Sure, although in this case we know that the variable contains an expansion that does not require quoting.

Comment: You only know that it doesn't require quoting if you also know the value of IFS. A parent process could export a surprising IFS value through the environment.